# Can't GROUP BY on column - alternative solution?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

```
SELECT journey.code, ADDTIME(journey.departure, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(link2.elapsed))) AS stopDeparture, service.line, getDestination(pattern.section), service.code
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
JOIN service ON service.code = journey.service
JOIN link ON link.section = pattern.section AND link.stop = "1000DMLF7767"
JOIN link link2 ON link2.section = pattern.section AND link2.id <= link.id
WHERE journey_day.day = 3 AND journey.code NOT IN   (SELECT journey
                                                     FROM journey_non_operation
                                                     WHERE "2014-10-15" BETWEEN date_start AND date_end)
GROUP BY stopDeparture, service.line
ORDER BY departure
```

When attempting to run the query above I see the following in the output log:

*Error Code: 1056. Can't group on 'stopDeparture'*

I'm not sure why this isn't possible, all I want to do is group the rows where the stopDeparture value and line value are the same.

Is there another way I can do this to avoid this error but achieve the desired result described above?

Comment: mb you need to set up alieases for tables?

`GROUP BY table1.stopDeparture, table2.line`

Comment: @mochalygin `stopDeparture` is a calculated value. It is not a column in "table1".

Comment: Did you try to replace `stopDeparture` with the expression you use in the `select` list?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No I haven't tried that, good idea, I shall give it a go now

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: You're GROUPING BY the thing you're summing. That makes no sense!

Comment: @Strawberry Why doesn't it? There are multiple rows with the same SUM value and line value, and I don't want to select rows with the same SUM value and line value, so I group by them.

Comment: @Strawberry Well then, perhaps you could post a comment/answer as to how it does work with an alternative solution, as I requested in the title?

Comment: @Strawberry Do you think that the best option would be to modify the output as I have described using the programming language requesting database data instead (in this case PHP)?

Comment: No - but I should confess to a bias when answering such questions. I think the best thing would be to start over, with our help, and following these (TWO) simple instructions... 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. Finally, if at all possible, leave the UDF out of the equation for the timebeing.

Comment: Arrgh! The pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` leads yet another developer into the depths of confusion. *Please* read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html  

A problem with this extension is that it allows gross underspecification of aggregate queries, and therefore makes it hard for other developers (like us on SO) to infer the purpose of a query from its text. That's a fancy way of saying "We, and the server, have to guess what you're trying to do and we might guess wrong."

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks Ollie! Will check out that link now. Been reading more about it and I'm starting to see how you're thinking.

Comment: How are there "multiple rows with the same SUM value and line value"? The SUM is a sum of several/many rows - which ones? That depends on the grouping, which is a RESULT of the SUM. So how can MySQL tell which rows belong together for summing them up if the decision is based on the result of the summary?? Maybe you don't need the SUM? If you just 'ADD_DATE(.. , ..) as stopDeparture' then you may be able to group by it, and if not, an inner select would help. I can show you how if you answer what the SUM is for :)